# Flex/AIR: DropDownList doesn't always open on click

Tags: apache-flex, drop-down-menu, air

I have an AIR application with 2-3 DropDownLists and a bunch of other controls. The DropDownLists are bound to dataproviders (ArrayCollections) in a central Model singleton. On launch, they all work fine.

However, when I click a button to add new objects to an object in another ArrayCollection in the same Model, the DropDownLists get weird. They still register clicks, and all other controls still work as before, but the dropdowns won't open. Clicking/waiting enough usually opens the dropdown, but if I don't make another selection it still won't open after closing. Making a different selection makes that DropDownList work again, but the others might still refuse to open.

If I open the dropdowns using Ctrl + Down arrow, they work all the time, so it's only the click that doesn't trigger the open correctly. I can work around the problem by calling `openDropDown()` on the dropdown when clicked, but that doesn't feel right.

I'm using the 4.1 SDK, and the dropdowns are s:DropDownLists. I tried using mx:ComboBoxes instead, but got the same behavior. **Edit:** Weirdly enough, using s:ComboBoxes they work as they should, but I really don't want to use them since they seemingly can't be made non-editable.

Has anyone run into this before and managed to solve it? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It's a completely random idea, but maybe trying 4.5 SDK could help?

Comment: @dain: Not completely random - I had the same one. Tried it, same issue.

Comment: Code please.  Seems you're doing something funky.

Comment: @J_A_X: I'm trying to create a sample, but it's a Cairngorm based app with events and commands and whatnot, so simulating it in a small sample app is a bit tricky.

Comment: You shouldn't of used Cairngorm :P

Comment: I hope you're kidding right?  We're talking Cairngorm 2?  Cairngorm is *the* worst application framework for Flex I have ever seen.  It isn't implementing MVC, it's tightly coupling **everything** you have to the ModelLocator (which is an anti-pattern), it's extremely slow, everything is view based (try to get one event to dispatch from one module to another) and it creates a ton of boilerplate code.  Application frameworks are suppose to *help* you code, not make it more difficult.  You should look into Parsley, Swiz or RobotLegs (I like parsley the most) for a good app framework.

Comment: @J_A_X: Not kidding, sorry. Yes, Cairngorm 2. I've enjoyed using it so far, but perhaps that's because of a lack of things to compare with - I'm still very much a newbie at flex development, and this is my first Cairngorm app. I'll look into the other frameworks you mentioned, but I doubt I'll be able to switch this app to anything else for now - it was behind schedule already when it started...

Comment: heh, yeah, Cairngorm 2 is 'archaic'.  You definitely should look up Parsley.  I also have a [workshop online](http://www.michelboudreau.com/2011/02/08/post-parsley-byol-workshop-summary/) if you want to learn it for your next project.

Comment: @J_A_X: thanks for the link and your input, will definitely look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a whole lot of tinkering with this, it seems that the problem appears when I have a ToggleButtonBar which has its `enabled` attribute set based on an attribute in the presentation model I have for the view. The other controls handle

```
enabled="{model.certainObject != null}"
```

perfectly fine, but not the ToggleButtonBar. It sets the attribute as it should, but somehow seems to cause the dropdown problem I've been having. Guess I won't be using a ToggleButtonBar...=/

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check:  Are you ArrayCollections marked Bindable in your Model Singleton?  Are your ArrayCollections bound to the values in the Model Singleton?

Binding is a strange beast; and if you are putting a lot of Bindable properties inside a single object; I understand that a change in one can trigger a chance in all bindable properties; which can ripple through the app if yu have a lot of different views all binding to that same Singleton object.

Another thing to check:  I have seen really weird results if you use the same Collection as the dataProvider to multiple ComboBoxes.  ( I assume the same odd behaviour would persist if using a multiple DropDownLists )

But, I'm just guessing here.  Most likely something is off in yor code.  Can you provide a runnable sample to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Yes, the entire Model is marked as Bindable, and the DropDownLists are bound to the ArrayCollections in the Model. No two dropdowns are bound to the same collection. I'll see if I can make a sample app which shows the problem, my current one is way too big to post.

Comment: I've now tried to separate the dataproviders of the dropdowns into (dummy) ArrayCollections in their base classes. They should be completely unlinked from the central model, but the issue occurs anyway. I've been unable to reproduce the issue in a sample app, unfortunately. Any other ideas? Do you think the Cairngorm 2 framework I'm using could be to blame?

Comment: @Lizzan If you can't reproduce it in a simple sample, then something in your code is causing it.  Without being able to isolate that issue; I do not believe there is anything we can do to help fix it.

Comment: Yes, it's probably something in my code (or just the size of the project), but I'm out of ideas of what to look for. Was only hoping for another suggestion or so...=) Thanks for your guesses, anyways!

Comment: Size of the project should have no affect.  If you wanted to do a screen share to step over code; you can give me a call through www.asktheflexpert.com .

Comment: Sorry, meant size of the Model, not the project. I'll keep the flexpert in mind if I don't succeed on my own...=)